# Docker IO Error with local js file

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-ec2, flask, docker

I am having hard time loading local js file with docker. I had no problem testing on local machine but if I host it on web server running on docker `No such file or directory: 'static/js/data.js` error.

My code is organized as follow:

```
Root/
  application.py

  static/
     js/
       data.js

  templates/
     index.html
```

And in `application.py` I am generating the file `data.js` and from `index.html` I read the file `data.js` with no problem `<script src="../static/js/data_data.js"></script>`

And in `application.py` I create a file using `file = open("static/js/data.js", "w+")` which works fine in local machine but not in web server (EC2)

And here's my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python-setuptools -y && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install python-setuptools -y 
RUN apt-get install python-pip -y
RUN apt-get install python-numpy -y
RUN apt-get install python-matplotlib -y
RUN apt-get install python-mysqldb -y
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev -y
RUN apt-get install python-psycopg2 -y
RUN apt-get install python-pandas -y
RUN pip install flask

ADD . /src

# Expose
EXPOSE  80

# Run
CMD ["python", "/src/application.py"]
```

Comment: Can you add more information how you ran your container ? Did you built your image using a specific Dockerfile ?

Comment: I think the file generated is saved somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't specify an absolute link in your application.

---

You can easily reproduce this problem on your local by doing

```
cd /
python /<pathtosrc>/src/application.py
```

---

Docker work directory is `/` by default.

So when you try to execute your program, it search for `/static/js/data.js`. but it doesn't exist.

You can solve the problem by using an absolute link, or by changing Docker work directory in your Dockerfile. Just add the following line at the end

```
# Run
CMD ["python", "/src/application.py"]
WORKDIR /src
```

Remember that `WORKDIR` will change the work directory for every command run after the `WORKDIR` line